# Can I use Amazon EventBridge input transformation behind APIGW as a SOAP/REST proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-event-bridge

Most APIs that I am supporting are still SOAP on the backend.

So, if I receive REST API calls, could I use Amazon EventBridge input transformation for REST to SOAP API convertor? Basically, like a API Proxy service.

Client -> APIGW -> EventBridge -> Lambda -> Services...

I know I can do it with Lamda behind the APIGW, but I could not understand if input transformation is for this or not.

I tried to explain my thoughts, and I am expecting someone to validate my use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use APIGW data transformation to transform your payload (e.g. convert json to XML) and then send it to EB to forward to your backend services.

You can also then transform the response from the backend service (e.g. from XML to JSON) and return to the client.

More info:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/rest-api-data-transformations.html
- https://serverlessland.com/patterns/apigateway-rest-eventbridge
- https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-transform-input-rule.html